# difference between 2 join in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have doubt in left join and right join
  If we consider as  2 tables A and B.
  A table has 10 records.
  B table has 15 records.

If left join A and B means will get 10 Records from A table.
  If Right join B and A means will get 10 Records from A table.

So both are same?, So what is the exact difference between  left and right join?

Answer (score 2):

`A LEFT B` and `B RIGHT A` which is the same:

You need to use `A LEFT B` and `A RIGHT B` to see diference

[image]

Comment: Minor note: the diagram shows `FULL OUTER JOIN`, which MySQL does not support.

Comment: Yes I accepted A LEFT B and B RIGHT A same. my question is left join is enough just swap the table name, it will comes answer. what purpose we use right join.  i want clear explanation. this example i already posted in stack over flow.

Comment: @SatheeshSivaNallathambi The clear explanation is you may have multiple joins and you need be able to use `A LEFT JOIN B ON... RIGTH JOIN C ON...` do you see why we need both right and left now?